# Unable to implement SCD2

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I was just working on SCD Type 2 and was unable to fully implement it in a way that some scenarios were not getting full filled. I had done it in IICS. Really finding it very very difficult to cover all possible scenarios. So, below is the flow:

```
Src 
---> Lkp ( on src.id = tgt.id)
 ---> expression ( flag= iif (isnull (tgt.surrogatekey) then Insert, iif(isnotnull(tgt.surrogatekey) and md5(other_non_key_cole)<>tgt.md5)then Update) 
----> insert on flag insert(works fine) 
but on update i pass updates
 to 2 target instances 
of same target table
in one i am updating it 
as new update as insert 
and in other i
am updating tgt_end_date=lkp_start_date for previously stored ids and active_ind becomes 'N'.
```

But what happens is this works but not in when i receive new updates with again same records meaning duplicates or simply rerunning the mapping inserts duplicates in the target table and changing of end_date also becomes unstable when i insert multiple changes of the same record it sets all active_flags  to 'Y' what expected is all should be 'N' except the last latest in evry run. Could anyone please help with this even in SQL if you can interpret.

Answer (score -1):

If I’ve understood your question correctly, in each run you have multiple records in your source that are matching a single record in your target.

If this is the case then you need to process your data so that you have a single source record per target record before you put the data through the SCD2 process

Comment: Yes, suppose number of changes i receive  is many for an id in the same source then how should the target load behave thats my first ask currently i have fixed the duplicates issue somewhat by doing Sql override in Source by left joining target on source to fetch new rows from source then the same flow as above. So, duplicates are getting avoided but suppose as i said i receive id with multiple changes on the same day eg id, change ; id, change1 ; so in target it should be id, change, 'N' and id, change1, Y but result is id, change, Y and id, change1, Y. Is this correct?

Comment: It is normal practice to only load the latest version of each record in your extract period i.e. if you load once a day then you’d take the state of each source record at the end of each day. If you want to load every (intra day) change then you need to run your loads at a high enough frequency to ensure only one version of the source record (i.e. every minute) or you’re going to have to design a custom SCD process that allows for multiple versions of the same source record in each load

Comment: So, is the current flow correct ? It updates the changes next time if i receive the same id with change again on the same day or later so its correct right evn though in one run it takes multiple Ys in the target if not run two times and is the approach correct to remove duplicates that is done by using target right join source and getting data from source on nulls in target

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea what your last comment means. The flow should be to take all the source records in each extract, where the same source record appears more than once construct a single record, pass this dataset into your SCD logic